# Images not pulling through for correct product

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason my images on each product don't pull through to my front end of my site.
It works when you click through to the actual product page but not on the index.php

http://www.tyresinwigan.co.uk/new/

```
<?php
require_once('const.php');
$link = dbConnect();

$query = "SELECT *, v.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id_alias 
FROM vehicle_tbl AS v, manufacturer_tbl AS m 
LEFT JOIN image_tbl AS i ON vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id 
WHERE v.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id AND v.vehicle_feature2 = '1' 
GROUP BY v.vehicle_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";

$result = false;
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
$fmain = false;
if (($result) && (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)) {
$fmain = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
mysql_free_result($result);
}

$query = "SELECT *, v.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id_alias 
FROM vehicle_tbl AS v, manufacturer_tbl AS m 
LEFT JOIN image_tbl AS i ON vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id 
WHERE v.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id AND v.vehicle_feature1 = '1' 
GROUP BY v.vehicle_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6";

$offers = false;
$offers = mysql_query($query, $link);

function nextOffer() {
    global $offers;
    if ($offers && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($offers))) {
    if (! isset($row['image_name'])) { // no image
        $image = 'images/noimagesml.jpg';
    } else {
        $image = 'images/vehicles/sml/'.stripslashes($row['image_name']);
    }
    $title = stripslashes($row['manufacturer_name']).' '.stripslashes($row['vehicle_model']);
    $price = number_format((float) $row['vehicle_price_pcm'], 2);
    $id = (int) $row['vehicle_id_alias'];
    echo '<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="contenthead"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="11" height="40" align="left" valign="top"><img src="images/featre_left_hd.gif" width="11" height="23"></td>
                            <td width="100%" align="left" valign="middle" class="contenthead">'.$title.'</td>
                            <td width="11" height="40" align="right" valign="top"><img src="images/featre_rght_hd.gif" width="11" height="23"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="contentpane"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="middle"><img src="'.$image.'" width="100" height="58" class="bordered" alt="'.$title.'"></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="princing">from just &pound'.$price.' pcm</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle"><a href="cardeal.php?vehicle='.$id.'"><img src="images/more_butt.gif" width="54" height="20" border="0"></a></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>';
    } else {
        echo 'Error!!';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "pull through"? There's an image of a man eating a record, both on the home page, and on the click-through page - is that not correct?

Comment: The best way to debug this is to run each of your queries in your database manually, and then see if the image paths retrieved are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your query for:

```
   SELECT *, 
          v.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id_alias 
     FROM vehicle_tbl AS v
     JOIN manufacturer_tbl AS m on v.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
LEFT JOIN image_tbl AS i ON v.vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id 
    WHERE v.vehicle_feature1 = '1' 
 GROUP BY v.vehicle_id 
 ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 6
```